# Get values from an element from a function with string parameter

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get the value of a field on a form when I call the update function.

```
   function update(gId, name, status){
      alert(gId);
      alert(name);
      alert(status); \\Works fine and displays the proper element name.
      alert(document.Form.status.value);\\Try to get the value of that element and it returns undefined.
    }
```

The gId, name and status are all Strings of elements Id's being passed into the update function. I have 3 dynamically created input fields that get updated. Ex: i_name, i_status, i_gid where i can be 0 or more. So when I call this update Im really passing in a string like 0_gid, 0_name, 0_status or 999_gId, 999_name, 999_status..ect.

pseudo form code.

```
<form>
input id&name=3_gId
input id&name=3_name
input id&name=3_status
Update(3_gId, 3_name, 3_status)
input id&name=11_gId
input id&name=11_name
input id&name=11_status
Update(11_gId, 11_name, 11_status)
</form>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just doing...

```
var text = document.getElementById(status).value;
alert(text);
```

or just put the `document.getElementById(status).value` in the alert

Comment: FML I did that at first and it didnt work I must have had a typo :(.

Comment: @user1857654 Okay let me know if it works and accept the answer if it does

Comment: I did I was on a 5 Min timer. Thanks for the quick reply +1